# $\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{f(0)}^{f(b)} \sqrt{|u|} \, \mathrm{d}u \quad \text{exists} \implies \lim_{b\to\infty } f(b) \quad \text{exists}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-explanation

I'm doing an exercise in which I think the below statement is true, but I can not prove it rigorously. Could you please elaborate if it's true or not. Thank you so much for your help!

> Consider $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable. $$\text{If} \quad\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{f(0)}^{f(b)} \sqrt{|u|} \, \mathrm{d}u \quad \text{exists, then} \quad\lim_{b\to\infty } f(b) \quad \text{exists} $$

**Update:** Assume $F(u)$ is the antiderivative of $\sqrt{|u|}$. If $f(0) \le f(b)$, then $$\int_{f(0)}^{f(b)} \sqrt{|u|} \, \mathrm{d}u = F(f(b)) - F(f(0)).$$

If $f(0) > f(b)$, then $$\int_{f(0)}^{f(b)} \sqrt{|u|} \, \mathrm{d}u = - F(f(b)) + F(f(0)).$$

Hence the sign of $f(b) - f(0)$ is important. And I can not tackle this sign.

Comment: Apply fundamental theorem of calculus + chain rule on $f$!

Comment: @rubikscube09 Could you please elaborate more? I suspect there would be subtle mistake because we do not know if $f(b) < f(0)$.

Comment: Why would it be relevant that $f(b) < f(0)$?  Would that prevent the limit from existing?  Would that prevent the integral from being well defined?  Who cares if the integral evaluates to a negative number?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Suppose that the statement is false and you'll be able to assume $f(b)<f(0)$ or $f(b)>f(0)$.

Comment: @TimurBakiev Again, I don't see the relevance of whether $f(b) < f(0)$.  Or is the point of your comment that there is no relevance?

Comment: This is necessary to calculate the integral using FTC. Then you'll see that the first limit does not exist -- a contradiction.

Comment: I have edit to add more information. Please see my update.

Comment: @TimurBakiev Unsure if your last comment was in response to my comment, since you didn't address it to user2661923.  If you are responding to my comment, could you please elaborate?  Admittedly, some of my Real Analysis knowledge has cobwebs on it.

Comment: The sign does not matter. Assume $f(0)>f(b)$, then we have $$ \int_{f(0)}^{f(b)} \sqrt{\vert u\vert} du = - \int_{f(b)}^{f(0)} \sqrt{\vert u \vert} du = - (F(f(0))-F(f(b)))  = F(f(b))-F(f(0)). $$

Comment: @user2661923 I somehow confused you with the author of this question, but yes, it was in response to your comment. In fact, the inequality doesn't really matter. However, it's very useful to assume $f(b) < f(0)$ or $f(b) > f(0)$ to simplify next steps.

Comment: Also note that $F'(x)=f(x)$ and thus $F$ is strictly monotonically increasing. Therefore, $F$ is invertible.

Comment: @TimurBaklev I guess you are right if you want to really compute the antiderivative, but I think that is not really needed as we can use that it is continuous and strictly monotone and thus its inverse is continuous as well, which finishes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

1.) We have
$$\int_{f(0)}^{f(b)} \sqrt{\vert u\vert } du =F(f(b))-F(f(0)).$$
See my comment above why the sign doesn't matter.

2.) Convergence of $\int_{f(0)}^{f(b)} \sqrt{\vert u\vert } du =F(f(b))-F(f(0))$ is equivalent to convergence of $F(f(b))$.

3.) We have $F'(x)=\sqrt{\vert x\vert}$, thus $F$ is strictly monotonically increasing and as $F$ is continuous, we also have that $F$ is a bijection on its image. Furthermore, the inverse of $F$ (defined on the image of $F$) is continuous.

4.) We have $f(b)= F^{-1} (F(f(b)))$.

5.) Conclude.

Comment: In my question, I just assume the existence of $F(u)$ for the sake presentation. How do we know $F$ exists?

Comment: The antiderivative exists by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that $u\mapsto \sqrt{\vert u\vert}$ is continuous (as composition of continuouus functions).

Comment: Of course, if you prefer, you can in this simple case also compute the antiderivative explicitely. But it is not needed for our purpose.